# How to display an error message on invalid url?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['link'] = request.form.get('link')
        link = YouTube(session['link'])
        return render_template('video.html', link=link)
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/download', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download():
    if request.method == "POST":
        link = YouTube(session['link'])
        itag = request.form.get('itag')
        video = link.streams.get_by_itag(itag)
        filename = video.download()
        return send_file(filename, as_attachment=True)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want my youtube downloader code to display an error message when the user enters an invalid URL or if the video is unavailable. It is showing an internal server error if the user enters an invalid URL.

After changes:

```
   @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def index():
       try:
          if request.method == 'POST':
             session['link'] = request.form.get('link')
             link = YouTube(session['link'])
             return render_template('video.html', link=link)
          return render_template('index.html')
       except:
           return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Now if the user enters the invalid URL the user gets redirected to the homepage but I want to Flash error message once the user gets redirected to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of you current API call, you can use the **catch metho**d with the new Fetch method in Javascript:

```
fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

The catch method triggers anytime when an error occurs. What you can do is specify different statements to output and check different crash criteria.

Sources:

- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)